# What are the special features that unlocked after finishing the game?

Tags: broken-sword-3

After completing the GOG version of [Broken Sword: The Sleeping Dragon](https://www.gog.com/game/broken_sword_3__the_sleeping_dragon) a notice appears stating that:

> You have unlocked a number of special features.

But the only feature I noticed a were the Concept Art Gallery. Is there anything else that have been unlocked ?